# Show that if a Banach space is generated by a countable set with finite dimension then it has finite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I don't know what to do with the following question:

> Show that if a Banach space is generated by a countable set with finite dimension then it has finite dimension

Supposedly it's related to the Baire theorem, but that didn't help me one bit. In fact it looks totally unrelated:

> **Theorem (Baire)** If $(G_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of open, dense subsets of the complete metric space $(X,d)$, then the intersection $\bigcap_{n \geq 1} G_n$ is dense in $X$.

So how would one go solving this?

Comment: The statement you have is what is usually known as the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) (you can find the proof in many functional analysis textbooks). What is the statement you know as the Baire theorem?

Comment: The only theorem with Baire's name in the textbook is that one. The question has the hint that Baire's theorem should help. But maybe the professor got the results mixed up.

Comment: Maybe I should just delete the theorem and see if someone can think of something else, it may be misleading.

Comment: Hi José. I just realized that I hadn't read the title of your question so I thought you were asking something else. I've edited your question so that the actual question is also reflected on the body. I've also edited my question (I originally had answer giving a sketch of proof for Baire's theorem) to show you how Baire's theorem implies that an infinite dimensional Banach space cannot have a countable base. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** At first I hadn't read the title of your question so I thought that you wanted to prove Baire's theorem and I added an answer based on that. My bad.

However, I do know how to show what you have on your title using Baire's theorem so here's a sketch:

I'll leave to you to check all the details.

The following statement is a direct consequence of Baire's theorem

> **Theorem.** If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space and $X=\bigcup_{n \geq 1} X_n$, then $\mathrm{int}(\overline{X_n}) \neq \varnothing$ for some $n$.

Now I will use the theorem to show that the algebraic dimension of a Banach space is either finite or uncountable:

Assume that $X$ is a Banach space generated by $\{ \xi_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\}$. For each $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ let $X_n$ be the space generated by $\{\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n\}$. Now it's standard to show that

- $X_n$ is closed
- $\mathrm{int}(X_n)= \varnothing$

Since $X$ is generated by these $X_n$'s, we have $X=\bigcup_{n \geq 1} X_n$. Thus, by the theorem above $\mathrm{int}(X_n) \neq \varnothing$ for some $n$, a contradiction.